# Can I change my credit card country in PSN?

Tags: psn

I've just changed country and moved from Italy to UK to work. I'd like to buy a game from PSN using my PSP and my new English credit card.

However it seems impossible to change my country in the billing address (and without changing it, my payment is refused).

Is there any way to switch my country from Italy to UK?

Comment: Pretty sure it's not possible. Workaround would be buying a PSN store card.

Comment: What about the sub accounts?

Comment: Have you asked PSN support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible, at least according to the UK site. (I assume the same is true in Italy; they don't seem to have the same screenshots on the Italian site, though.)

When you create a Sony Entertainment Network account, you set your country of residence - in your case, Italy. This can't be changed later, as indicated in [these screenshots](http://uk.playstation.com/psn/support/ps3/detail/linked235311/item269156/Create-a-Sony-Entertainment-Network-account-on-your-PS3%2C-and-access-PlayStation-Network-for-free-/). Because the country in the billing address for any forms of PSN payment [must match your indicated country of residence](http://faq.en.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/673/p/0), you can't add a credit card from any other country or change the country of an existing credit card.